# Is there a way to also add the date associated with the ID to my Plotly graph?

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly

I have a dataset, data, with the following values:

```
   ID                TIME                         Duration   
    A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM        1 sec
    A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM        0 sec                    
    B                12/19/2019 4:14:13 AM        7 sec
    B                12/19/2019 4:14:20 AM        0 sec
    A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM        0 sec
```

I have 3 columns which consists of the ID, the TIME, and the Duration. I wish to group by ID as well as Time and plot the Duration of the ID using plotly. So far everything works great, I am just having trouble adding the Time to the bars on the graph. I have included a pic within this post.

```
   ID                TIME                         Duration   
    A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM        1 sec
    A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM        0 sec
    A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM        0 sec                    
    B                12/19/2019 4:14:13 AM        7 sec
    B                12/19/2019 4:14:20 AM        0 sec
```

```
   df1<-df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Duration.order = sum(as.numeric(Duration))) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(ID.order = reorder(ID, Duration.order))
```

```
 plot_ly(data = df1,
 x = ~ID.order,
 y = ~Duration,
 name = "Title",
 type = "bar",
 orientation = 'v',
 order = "ascending") %>%
 layout(title = "Time Graph",
 xaxis = list(title = "Message ID", tickangle = -45),
 yaxis = list(title ="Time in Seconds"))
```

However, I would like to also add the Date that is associated with the IDs to this graph. I am still working on this.

[image]

Data: df1 structure

```
ID = C ("A", "A", "B", "B", "A")

Date = C ("12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM", "12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM",
"12/19/2019 4:14:13 AM", "12/19/2019 4:14:20 AM",
"12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM")

 Duration = structure (C (1, 0, 7,0, 0)
 class = "difftime", units = "secs"
```

Comment: Where are you trying to see the dates? The X axis? Hovertext?

Comment: Yes, Hovertext or the Xaxis. I am looking at the documentation now, I am not seeing how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With provided data, made changes.  This will make the hovertext be the Date values.  If you want it to say the ID number, try changing to 'name = ~ID'

```
ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A")

Date = c("12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM", "12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM", "12/19/2019 4:14:13 AM", "12/19/2019 4:14:20 AM", "12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM")

Duration = c(1, 0, 7,0 , 0)

df1 <- data.frame(ID, Date, Duration)


plot_ly(data = df1,
        x = ~ID,
        y = ~Duration,
        text = ~Date,
        hovertemplate = paste('%{text}'),
        name = "Title",
        type = "bar",
        orientation = 'v',
        order = "ascending") %>%
  layout(title = "Time Graph",
         xaxis = list(title = "Message ID", tickangle = -45),
         yaxis = list(title ="Time in Seconds"))
```